# Section headers getting reset for Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a expandable tableview with custom headers. When I load the tableview I set the alpha for few sections based on if they have any items in it.

[image: Initial State]

I set the alpha back to 1 once I have some items in those sections.

The problem I am facing is as soon as I click on any of the section to expand that section, it just resets the view for all headers that are below the clicked one and just removes the alpha. For Ex If I click on 1st one, all the headers become alpha 1 but if I click on the 4th one, just the 4th and 5th become alpha 1. For ex If I click on 1 this is how it shows -

[image: 1st selected one]

In order to achieve the collapsable and expandable view, I use the following code to refresh the section -

```
    let indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet(integer: section)
    self.filterTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.filterTableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)
    self.filterTableView.endUpdates()
```

The way I set the header is shown below -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "FilterOptionHeaderView") as! FilterOptionHeaderView

    let filterHeader = self.filterHeaders[section]
    let selectedCount = self.selectedItems[filterHeader.key]?.count ?? 0
    if selectedCount > 0 {
        headerView.headerLabel.text = filterHeader.name + "(\(selectedCount))"
    } else {
        headerView.headerLabel.text = filterHeader.name
    }

    headerView.tag = kHeaderSectionTag + section

    let headerTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    headerTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sectionHeaderTapped(_:)))
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(headerTapGesture)

    if self.sectionItems[section].isEmpty || self.sectionItems[section].count < 1 {
        headerView.alpha = 0.5
    } else {
        headerView.alpha = 1
    }

    return headerView
}
```

I have tried setting the alpha in `didEndDisplayingHeaderView` as well but still doesn't work. Please let me know how to achieve this. I know that all the headers are reset because the arrow of the expanded direction also comes back to initial state even though i have rotation animation in place that shows up and then resets.

Comment: When you "expand" a section, and the other section headers change, is `viewForHeaderInSection` being called again for every section?

Comment: No it just gets called for 1 section with the index of the one i clicked. So if I click on 1st the view for header is called once with index 0

Comment: Hmm... when I try this, and I set `headerView.alpha = 0.5`, it doesn't seem to apply at all. Perhaps it's the way I set up the custom header view. However, because of the way section header/footer views are handled, I suspect your alpha setting is being overridden. Try configuring your view so you can set the alpha of the view's `.contentView`.

Comment: As a side note, because the views are reused, you are adding a **new** `UITapGestureRecognizer` each time... you should put that in your custom view's init code and use either a protocol/delegate pattern or a "callback" closure.

Comment: Yep for now i added a shortcut to just tap and move forward. i was about to put it inside the customView. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Also for the alpha, I think it started showing up when i added the code for alpha setting in willDisplayHeaderView. Let me try removing that to see what happens